# Windows 7 got error. Net framework application 4.0 (written with WinXP SP3)

Tags: c#, .net

What am I doing wrong? I have application, which run normally, but when I press button in Win 7 (search in Google) that assigns

`hl.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com.ua/#hl=ru&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=933&q=");`

it Crashes. What am I doing wrong? On Windows XP SP3 machine it normally works..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bool google = true;

        if (((Button)sender).Content.ToString() == "Google")
            google = true;
        else
            google = false;
        Run run1 = new Run(textBox1.Text);
        Hyperlink hl = new Hyperlink(run1);
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        //Label label1 = new Label();
        //label1.Content = textBox1.Text;
        //label1.Tag = ;
        if (google)
            hl.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com.ua/#hl=ru&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=933&q=");
        else
            hl.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=");
        hl.Tag = i;
        hl.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(hl_Click);
        tb.Inlines.Add(hl);
        tb.Inlines.Add(" ");
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tb);
        if (google)
        {
            col1_links.Add("http://www.google.com.ua/#hl=ru&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=933&q=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            col1_links.Add("http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text));
        }
        col1_texts.Add(textBox1.Text);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(col1_links[i].ToString());
        i++;
        SaveData();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if the error was in english!

Comment: Btw, you could shorten your code a tad.  `bool google = ((Button)sender).Content.ToString() == "Google";`

Comment: It says. "Stopped working progrma, Windows trieng search method to dismiss error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can rewrite your code in a few lines:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var google = ((Button)sender).Content.ToString() == "Google";
        var run1 = new Run(textBox1.Text);
        var hl = new Hyperlink(run1)
        {
            NavigateUrl = google ? "http://www.google.com.ua/#hl=ru&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=933&q=" :
                                   "http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=";
            Tag = i;
        };
        var tb = new TextBlock();
        hl.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(hl_Click);
        tb.Inlines.Add(hl);
        tb.Inlines.Add(" ");
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tb);
        col1_links.Add(hl.NavigateUrl + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text));
        col1_texts.Add(textBox1.Text);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(col1_links[i].ToString());
        i++;
        SaveData();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Try to be more professional ;) . First of all, NavigateUrl is "string" (not Uri), try to use this (not NavigateUri). Second thing is there is no "i" variable, where is it?

Comment: Artem Makarov. Thanks for Replay. I used NavigateURL not the URI. But... In code was unnessarry string (all HyperLinks are assigned in EventHandler hl_Click) But what's about the PROBLEM. It WAS 4.0 framework. I changed to 3.5 and it works perfectly. If someone is interesting in my work — you can download my work here [MyWork_InternetExplorer & RTFEditor][1]


  [1]: http://www.mediafire.com/file/b3koqxk0wlva7l3/CloseableTabItemDemo.rar

Comment: i is private member variable. :)

Comment: If you want the answer, please give me the whole code, EXE is nothing :) ... And .Net4 is definitely not the problem

Comment: no problem if you don't know solution - just changed version to 3.5. And Method Navigate of WebBrowser support URI (imenno a ne String). So just for interest, I'll check it back later. :-)

Comment: Oh, God... I'm blind! Please, read good books about how to write your code... :) I don't have enough time to deal with it :)